# Can an Alchemist Artificer use Alchemical Savant on the casting of a spell with no Material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components, artificer

I have looked for any rules on this and cannot find any, and before you say "It doesn't matter flavour however you like", I have a specific example.

In the alchemist subclass for the artificer class the 5th level feature **Alchemical Savant** reads:

> Whenever you cast a spell using your alchemist’s supplies as the spellcasting focus

Does this mean that if the spell has no material components  that it cannot use this feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### All Artificer spells have material components and require a focus.

With the [November 2020 errata to the Artificer class](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/ERftLW-Errata.pdf), the [Artificer’s Spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#Spellcasting-1131501) now reads:

> You must have a spellcasting focus—specifically thieves’ tools or some kind of artisan’s tool—in hand when you cast any spell with this Spellcasting feature (**meaning the spell has an ‘M’ component when you cast it**).

You must have a focus to cast any of your artificer spells, which means every artificer spell you cast has an M component, even if the spell description doesn’t say it has M components.

Comment: I see now I should have been even more specific, I will edit the question to reflect this (the spell was magic missile which is not an artificer spell).

Comment: actually, I will make a new question. As it's actually a sepparate issue.

Comment: actually never mind again, I found my own answer in the multiclassing rules. Your answer is correct and did help me come to my conclusion though. Thankyou.